# How to assign categories to a new product automatically?

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento and not familiar with it. My requirement is to assign a category to new products automatically. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have fixed category to assign when new product is saved then it can be done by observer event (like `catalog_product_save_after`).

When product is saved, in observer you can write code to assign that newly saved product to particular category.

Following is snippet to assign product to category.

```
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
$categories[] = $categoryId;
$product->setCategoryIds($categories);
$product->save();
```

Comment: Using `->save()` in this context generates a "DUPLICATE ENTRY" error, because the product ends up being saved twice 